# How to slice a list in Python

Tags: python, list

Suppose I have a list with X elements

```
[4,76,2,8,6,4,3,7,2,1...]
```

I'd like the first 5 elements.  Unless it has less than 5 elements.

```
[4,76,2,8,6]
```

How to do that?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/good-primer-for-python-slice-notation

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You just subindex it with `[:5]` indicating that you want (up to) the first 5 elements.

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8][:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [1,2,3][:5]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x = [6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
>>> x[:5]
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Also, putting the colon on the right of the number means count from the nth element onwards -- don't forget that lists are 0-based!

```
>>> x[5:]
[11, 12]
```

Comment: This is commonly known as slicing.

Comment: This creates a *new* list, it doesn't trim the existing one. To trim in-place, use `del` on a slice; e.g. `del listobj[-x:]` will remove the last *x* elements from the list object.

Answer (score 46):

To trim a list in place without creating copies of it, use `del`:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> # delete elements starting from index 4 to the end
>>> del t[4:]
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> # delete elements starting from index 5 to the end
>>> # but the list has only 4 elements -- no error
>>> del t[5:]
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [4,76,2,8,6,4,3,7,2,1]
l = l[:5]
```

Comment: @too Of course, this is only made for demonstration purposes :D

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9][:5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> [1,2,3][:5]
[1, 2, 3]
```