# How do I truncate a list?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list and want to truncate it so it is no more than 100 items, how do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534939/how-to-trim-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 105, accepted):

To modify the list in place (rather than make a shorter copy of the list), use:

```
del l[100:]
```

Comment: slicing with a[:100] is generally a better solution since it has constant performance, but del a[100:] becomes slower for larger list.

Comment: kefeizhou: That might depend on what you actually want.  If you really don't need the entries beyond the first 100 any more, you should delete them.  Saying it is generally a better idea to keep them lying around because this takes less time than deleting them seems strange reasoning to me.

Comment: `del l[100:]` seems to not result in a copy of the elements (`id(l)` does not change, and at a low level, I can't see why a copy would be needed), which would give another reason to use this solution. Does `l[:100]` result in a copy of the elements? even in the case of `l[:] = l[:100]`?

Answer (score 20):

You can use list slicing:

```
a = a[0:100]
```

Comment: And if you absolutely insist on freeing the unused remainder: del  a[100:]

Comment: @Confusion: the remainder gets garbage collected automatically if `a` was the only reference to the list.

Answer (score 7):

The `items[:100]` other mentioned gives you a new list which contains the first 100 items of `items`. If you want to modify the list in-place, <del>either use `items[:] = items[:100]` (slice assignment) or `while len(items) > 100: items.pop()`</del>use `del items[100:]` as proposed by Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 3):

You can use slicing if you don't mind just simply creating a new copy of the list that contains only the elements you want... however this leaves the original list unmodified.

```
>>> a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> b = a[0:5]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> b
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If you really want to truncate the original list, just delete the elements you don't want by using slicing with **del**

```
>>> del a[5:]
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
truncated = list[:100]
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is, of course:

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x = x[:5]
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

But, importantly, if you're interested in the values above 100 and want to pull them off one by one for whatever reason, you can also use **POP()**

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> x.pop()
9
>>> x
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You can even specify which element to pull out:

```
>>> x= range(10,20)
>>> x
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> x.pop(3)
13
>>> x.pop()
19
>>> x
[10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
>>> x.pop(-1)
18
[10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17]
```

**This removes individual elements, shortening the list, without copying.**

So, an obtuse and yucky answer (but also correct) would be to iterate down.  I'm only going down from 12 to 8 for ease of reading here:

```
>>> x=range(12)
>>> for i in range(len(x), 8, -1):
...     y = x.pop()
...     print "popping x: ", y, ", x=", x
...
popping x:  11 , x= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
popping x:  10 , x= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
popping x:  9 , x= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
popping x:  8 , x= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Sure, it's not optimal, but I just ran into a situation where I needed this so I thought I'd share it here (I'm truncating a list when I see the first not-None value).

Comment: "This removes individual elements, shortening the list, without copying." From what I've read, `x.pop(3)` doesn't happen without copying. Instead, every element after the 3rd is shifted (copied) left one slot.