# Is there any way I can get rid of the [] in the beginning? Python

Tags: python

My code is to get the combination of the user's input but I want to remove the [] at the start of the output. How can I do it? And is there any way to change my output to `[[1],[2],[3],[1,2]...]`?

```
def combination(number):
    if len(number) == 0:
        return [[]]
    cs = []
    for c in combination(number[1:]):
        cs += [c, c+[number[0]]]
    return cs
    
number = [1, 2, 3]
print(combination(number))
```

Currently, I am getting the following output:

```
[[], [1], [2], [2, 1], [3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Are you aware that itertools have a function for this called combinations (see [docs.python.org/...#itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)) which returns an iterator over you combinations?

Comment: Yes, I am aware but I want to solve this problem using different approach without using any import.

Comment: What if you just print all elements leaving out the first one? Like this `print(combination(number)[1:])`

Comment: I can't because the unit test will fail

Comment: You can try [removing the first element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534939/how-to-slice-a-list-in-python).